# Re-insert in Table after Selecting records from Same table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I want to fetch records from a table and re-insert those in the same table

Table Data -

| Name | Address | Sub1 | Sub2 | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Add1 | SubA | SubO | 1 |
| A | Add2 | SubA | SubM | 1 |
| B | AddB | SubB | SubO | 2 |
| C | AddC | SubC | SubO | 2 |

I have multiple Names(B,C,D.. around 40 ) with Type 2 records  and only Name A with Type1.

I want to insert Type2  records with column entries of Type1, meaning the table after my insert should look like this-

| Name | Address | Sub1 | Sub2 | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Add1 | SubA | SubO | 1 |
| A | Add2 | SubA | SubM | 1 |
| B | AddB | SubB | SubO | 2 |
| B | Add1 | SubA | SubO | 2 |
| B | Add2 | SubA | SubM | 2 |
| C | AddC | SubC | SubO | 2 |
| C | Add1 | SubA | SubO | 2 |
| C | Add2 | SubA | SubM | 2 |

How can I form select from this table and re-insert in the same table?

Answer (score 2):

Use `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```sql
INSERT INTO data (name, address, sub1, sub2, type)
SELECT n.name, d.address, d.sub1, d.sub2, 2
FROM   data d
       CROSS JOIN (
         SELECT DISTINCT
                name
         FROM   data
         WHERE  name <> 'A'
       ) n
WHERE  type = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE data (Name, Address, Sub1, Sub2, Type) AS
SELECT 'A', 'Add1', 'SubA', 'SubO', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'Add2', 'SubA', 'SubM', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'AddB', 'SubB', 'SubO', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'AddC', 'SubC', 'SubO', 2 FROM DUAL;
```

After the `INSERT` then the table contains:

> | NAME | ADDRESS | SUB1 | SUB2 | TYPE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | A | Add1 | SubA | SubO | 1 |
> | A | Add2 | SubA | SubM | 1 |
> | B | AddB | SubB | SubO | 2 |
> | C | AddC | SubC | SubO | 2 |
> | B | Add1 | SubA | SubO | 2 |
> | B | Add2 | SubA | SubM | 2 |
> | C | Add1 | SubA | SubO | 2 |
> | C | Add2 | SubA | SubM | 2 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b77e35da41b41037925b278945acdd88)*

Comment: Thank you, this works. One additional question, will this query be efficient if type1 data increases with time ? Any scope of tuning this query ?

Comment: @sqlpractice If your initial conditions hold (only name A with type 1) and you want to insert the rows as type 2 of all the other types then how do you expect to make it more efficient or tune it? This does what you want and, if your initial conditions keep holding for next time then, next time it will still do what you want.